# php- Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object using INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, binding

I'm pretty new to php/MySQL and this error is really stumping me. I've looked through previous questions about this error, but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm binding my parameters to prevent SQL injection.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$into = 'INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

$name = str_replace("'", "_", $_POST[name]);
$message = str_replace("'", "_", $_POST[message]);
$recipient = str_replace("'", "_", $_POST[recipient]);
$destination = str_replace("'", "_", $_POST[destination]); 
$room = str_replace("'", "_", $_POST[roomnumber]);
$anonymous = $_POST[anonymous];
$offcampus = $_POST[off_campus];
$offcampusaddress = str_replace("'", "_", $_POST[offcampusaddress]);

$stmt = $con->prepare($into);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $name, $recipient, $destination, $room, $message, $anonymous, $offcampus, $offcampusaddress);
```

The bind_param line is the one that causes the error. I know a lot of times this error is due to a small syntax mistake, but I can't seem to find any. Is there something obvious that I am missing? This is my first run at binding parameters, so I might not understand it correctly.

Comment: Since `bind_param()` is being done on `$stmt`, have you checked that `$stmt = $con->prepare($into);` did not fail? is your connection `$con` good. Is your query - `$into` valid, ie. does `Orders` have 8 columns?

Answer (score 0):

### Primary Issue

Replace

```
&offcampus,
```

with

```
$offcampus,
```

**Here...**

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $name, $recipient, $destination, $room, $message, $anonymous, &offcampus, $offcampusaddress);
                                                           ---------------------------------^
```

### Secondary Issue

The **`$_POST`** params which you have enclosed on `single quotes` will **never** be parsed. For e.g.

```
$anonymous = '$_POST[anonymous]';
```

Replace it with

```
$anonymous = $_POST['anonymous'];
```

Similarly, do this for all your other variables assignment too

Comment: Hmm that wasn't the problem, I had it that way to begin with. Changing it back does not help

Comment: The primary issue what i have put is the first concern as it gives you a syntactical error. The secondary issue is that you will face after you insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

change `&offcampus` to `$offcampus`